# SSRS Report on PBI Server showing saved data in parameters

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, reportbuilder, power-bi-report-server

I am building a SSRS report in Power BI Report Builder and the parameters should never suggest/save any data.

When I run the report in Report Builder it works as expected, however once I publish it and run it on the PBI Server, each parameter saves and suggests my previous entries. Is there a way to disable this? If so, is it on the Report Builder side or the Server side?

The parameters are currently setup to be text entry only with no blank/null/default values allowed. There is one ID entry parameter and two date parameters.

Caching is set to "always run this report with the most recent data" on the server.

Comment: It could be a setting with the browser itself.

Comment: I agree with aduguid. This is most likely the browser 'AutoComplete' and nothing directly related to SSRS. You can disable this within the browser settings but I don't think you can disable it only for specific sites.